# Calling a sub and passing an argument in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, controls

I'm trying to call a sub (OnAction) and passing an argument from a toolbar control, but I cannot seem to call it as I keep getting "Cannot run the macro. The macro may not be available".

The control is in a workbook and the function in a module.

```
Option Explicit

Sub somefunction(Optional ServerType As String) End Sub
```

Here's the code for the Control:

```
With ToolsMenuControl

    .Caption = "some caption"
    .OnAction = "'" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'!someFunction ""Wintel""'"
    .Tag = C_TAG

End With
```

Please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that correct `.OnAction property` assignment depends on whether file is saved or not. Therefore there are to possible syntax presented below:

```
    If ThisWorkbook.Saved Then
        'when your file is saved
        .OnAction = "'" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'!'somefunction ""Saved""'"
    Else
        'when file is not saved
        .OnAction = ThisWorkbook.Name & "!'somefunction ""Not Saved""'"
    End If
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is really helpful. Where did you get this information?

Comment: I found it out by chance. I had made successfully the second option which  stopped working after I saved the file.

Comment: KazJaw, now I'm trying to add a variable there too:             .OnAction = ThisWorkbook.Name & "!'somefunction "" & path & ""'" Unfortunately this is passing the path literally. any idea how I can get it to work?

Comment: @KrisVandenBergh, too much or too less of quotation marks :) Try this one: `.OnAction = ThisWorkbook.Name & "!'somefunction """ & path & """'"`

Answer (score 0):

1. Excel uses `Path!Reference` to refer either Cells or Macros. Path may be FileName or FullPath, (and SheetName for cell referencing). Reference may refer a cell address, or, Macro with arguments.
2. For both Path and Reference, enclose within apostrophes(') if it contains special characters.

   - Paths e.g.: `Book1.xlsx` or `'C:\Users\Me\My Book.xlsx'`. @KazJaw, file naming and paths will show differences when referring unSaved/Open/Closed files.
   - References e.g.: `mySub` or `'someFunction "Wintel" '`. Extra spaces left for readability, truncated by interpreter.
3. Strings in VB are enclosed in quotes (" "). Recommended way to embed quotes/apostrophes within strings is to double up on the quote used. e.g.

   - Use `'He''s good'` to represent `He's good`
   - `"Am ""I"" fine?"` translates to `Am "I" fine?`
4. Writing in VB, `.OnAction = "'" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'!'someFunction ""Wintel"" ' "`.